# VS Code extension that supports preview for markdown inline math wrapped in escaped parenthesis?

Tags: math, markdown, latex, visual-studio-code

Background / use case: https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/386/how-does-chatgpt-render-math-in-markdown-output

The `\( ... \)` syntax in markdown corresponds to LaTex math inline mode.

Example:

ChatGPT Web UI renders this markdown output `is \( 2^4 = 16 \).`

as:

[image]

Is there a VS Code extension that will allow me to preview markdown files with such inline math notations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of extensions supporting this, I'm personally using [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced), which supports bunch of different math syntaxes and also other non-standard extensions such as PlantUML.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It works for me. Do you happen to know a tool that allows me to convert markdown with such math notation to PDF?

Comment: That's for a separate question, but pandoc is a quick example